# Java: How to create a new folder in Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, directory

I want to create a folder in ex. my desktop in Mac OS X

I try to use this code, instead of Mymac is my name of course:)

```
String path="/Users/Mymac/Desktop";
String house = "My_home";
File file=new File(path);
if(!file.exists())
    file.mkdirs(); // or file.mkdir()

file=new File(path + "/" + house);   
try {
  if(file.createNewFile())
   {
   }
} catch (IOException ex) {

  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Do you know how I could create a new folder? 
And another thing is when I want to create a folder in the directory where my code is, do you know how I could write that? I have tried

```
   String path="./";

   String path="::MyVolume";

   String path=".";
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package javax.media.j3d is sealed in my main method, which was running before adding this code.

Comment: then you are importing wrong libraries, or another part of your code is wrong. This code definitifly runs without exception (see my answer)

Comment: I will try it and I will tell you the results:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the folder/directory where one of your classes is (assuming they are not in a Jar), and then to create a subfolder there:

```
    String resource = MyClass.class.getName().replace(".", File.separator) + ".class";      
    URL fileURL = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(resource);

    String path = new File(fileURL.toURI()).getParent();
    String mySubFolder = "subFolder";
    File newDir = new File(path + File.separator + mySubFolder);
    boolean success = newDir.mkdir();
```

(The code above could be made more compact, I listed it more verbosely to demonstrate all the steps.) Of course, you need to be concerned about permission issues.  Make sure that the user which is running java has permission to create a new folder.

Comment: I guess I have to import 
import javax.print.DocFlavor.URL;
right?

Comment: @DimitraMicha: you need to add: `import java.net.URL;`

Answer (score 3):

A platform-independent way:

```
File rootDir = File.listRoots()[0];
File dir = new File(new File(new File(rootDir, "Users"), "Mymac"), "Desktop");
if (!dir.exists()){
    dir.mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: This will not actually create the directory. A `File` object is just a representation of a path name - creating a `File` object doesn't also create the file or directory on disk.

Comment: I think the OP already knows that (as well as me, of course ;-) ), as the code shown in the question already uses "file.mkdirs()". It just helps with platform specific file path delimiters and root directories.

Comment: Well, actually I think it was more readable before. I change it back ;-)

Comment: Besides, it's safer than System.getProperty("file.separator") (you could have a typo in "file.separator", which the compiler wouldn't catch)

Comment: I don't agree in this point: Creating several unneccessary objects to prevent a possible typo of the programmer isn't "best practice".

Comment: Well, then we disagree on this point, as I favor compile-time safety over avoiding a couple (small number) additional objects. And it's more readable IMHO. It would be nice if the API would provide a better way, though. And favoring readability and compile-time safety over micro-optimizations without need (e.g. first profiling) _is_ best practice, IMHO.

Comment: @Puce: `File.separator` is a static class property. It won't compile if there's a typo. Another point against your approach is that if your folder is 15 sub-directories deep, you'll end up with something like: `new File(new File(new File(new File(new File(new File(new File(new File(new File(new File(...))))))))))` - Difficult to read, and easy to get lost on the parenthesis.

Comment: True, I read it too quickly and mixed it with Erics answer who uses System.getProperty. So this argument doesn't hold anymore. ;-)
Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The nice part is the last bit, where 'rootDir, "Users"), "Mymac"), "Desktop")' is almost like rootDir / "Users" / "Mymac" / "Desktop"

Comment: Usually you seldom have 15 levels of hardcoded directory names, and if you have, String concatenation with File.separator gets very long as well. The IDE can help you with the paranthesis. Anyway, File.separator is much better than System.getProperty("file.separator").

Comment: The idea to use File.listRoots()[0] save me a lot of time when trying to test/create a file in MacOS.

Comment: Please, note that since Java SE 7 there is now the NIO.2 File API, which provides Path.get and FileSystem.getDafault().getRootDirectories(). Using the NIO.2 File API should be preferred over the legacy java.io.File class, which at that time I suggested in my answer. This also solves the issue of creating several File objects.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok and will work. Perhaps you have a typo in your username in your file-path ("Mymac"), so you don't see the changes, since they go to another folder.

Running this code on my machine works fine and gives the expected result.

To make your code platform-independant, you can build your file-path with the following trick:

```
File path = new File(File.listRoots()[0], "Users" + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "Mymac" + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "Desktop"));
```

If "My_home" should be a folder and not a file, you have to change the `file.createNewFile()` - command. More detailed information you'll find in the answer of Thomas.

Comment: The code, however, would create a file `My_home` in `/Users/Mymac/Desktop`, not a folder.

Comment: The path is relative, though.

Comment: But that is not platform-independent, as you mentioned (e.g. Windows "c:")

Answer (score 0):

Use `file.mkdir()` or `file.mkdirs()` instead of `file.createNewFile()` and it should work, if you have permission to create new folders and files.

`mkdirs()` will create the subfolders if they don't exist, `mkdir()` won't.

To create a directory in your base directory (the one you start your application from), just provide a relative path name: `new File("mydir").mkdir();`

*Edit*: to make file handling easier, I'd suggest you also have a look at Apache Commons' [`FilenameUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-2.1/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html) and [`FileUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-2.1/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html).

Comment: I haven't downvoted your answer, but I can imagine why: he IS using mkdirs to create the folders first.

Comment: @Erik, well I assume he wants to create a _folder_ `My_home`, at least that's what the post implies. There's nothing mentioned about creating a file.

Comment: that's true - in this way you can understand his request too. +1 from me