# How to load resources consistently in applet and desktop-app?

Tags: java, image, applet, load, media

I have a desktop application, and I would like to have an applet-version of it.
I want the jar to be executable, and capable of being run as an applet.

I have a `GamePane` class that extends `JPanel` and loads some media from the media folder in the following manner:

```
File f = new File("media/path/to/file");
```

How do I modify this so that the media loads correctly, regardless of whether the jar is run as an executable, or as an applet?

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714294/java-getcodebase-on-non-applet-application), but none of the suggestions work, at-least not in development when the code being run is inside the `bin` folder, instead of a jar. If it only works with the jar, then is there any way to make the dev-process less painful?

My directory structure is:

```
Game->
    media
    game.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the media files inside the jar, which will make them available from the classpath, and use

```
MyClass.class.getResource("/media/foo.png")
```

or

```
MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/media/foo.png")
```

to have access to the media (as an URL or as a stream).

During development, since you want the media to be loaded from the classpath, it simply means that the media must be stored inside your source folder: the IDE will copy them for you to the target directory (i.e. where .class files are generated by the compiler).

Comment: what if i *have* to have it outside the jar?

Comment: Then parameterize your app / applet with a base URL (pointing either at a file or at the document base), and use URLs to load the media. An URL is an abstaction over multiple ways to access resources.

Comment: *"what if i have to have it outside the jar?"*  When/why does that come up?